Selecting elements in HTML using tree generator extension
I have recently been trying to understand how to select elements and manipulate them using the html tree generator and JavaScript. How do I select the second last element of the last element child and also how do I select the links in order to manipulate them.
To select the second last element in the last element child I tried using :
document.firstElementChild.lastElementChild.lastElementChild.lastElementChild

.....but I still get a null hence cant change the element value.

try to use document.body.firstElementChild.lastElem...

You need to select the second last element of the last element child. That needs to be checked conditionally.
Refer the code below for more reference:


var lastElementChild = document.firstElementChild.lastElementChild;
if (lastElementChild && lastElementChild.children.length >= 2) { // Check last element available and it has children 
    var secondLastElement = lastElementChild.children[lastElementChild.children.length - 2]; // if above is truthy then select the second last child of lastElementChild
    secondLastElement.textContent = "New Value"; // Now change the second element
} else {
    console.log("Unable to find the second last element.");
}




@KepherAshitakaya appreciate it if you could mark it as the correct answer. :-)

Selecting the Second Last Element of the Last Element Child:
const lastElementChild = document.body.lastElementChild;

const children = lastElementChild.children;
const secondLastElement = children[children.length - 2];

Selecting and Manipulating Links
const allLinks = document.querySelectorAll('a');

allLinks.forEach(link => {
    link.textContent = ""; 
    link.href = ""; 
});


Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it

When working with .firstElementChild or .lastElementChild methods of DOM elements you need to go through the whole chain of elements (incl. <ul> elements), whereas if you use CSS selectors like li:last-child you can concentrate on <li> elements only. This can make the selection process shorter and easier to handle:


var chn = document.body
 .firstElementChild // ul
 .lastElementChild  // Last li
 .firstElementChild // ul
 .children;         // lis
console.log(chn[chn.length-2]);

// alternatively, with CSS selectors:
console.log(document.body.querySelector("li:last-child li:nth-last-child(2)"));
   
<ul>
 <li>one</li>
 <li>two</li>
 <li>here is the next level:
  <ul><li>three</li>
   <li>four</li>
   <li>this is it!</li>
   <li>five</li>
  </ul></li>
</ul>



The CSS pseudo class :nth-last-child(2) will get you the penultimate element in a collection of children.

Thank you for your answer Sir and taking the time to respond. Really appreciated
